# feval with multivariate function and vectorization

Tags: matlab, if-statement, vectorization

I need feval called with a bivariate function f and two vectors v1 and v2 (let us say that v1 are the x's and v2 the y's) to return a vector z=[f(v1(1),v2(1)) ... f(v1(n),v2(n)].
How can I do that ?

The following example does not work:

```
function z = f(x,y)
if x>0.5
z=x+y;
else
z=x+2*y;
end
end
```

indeed,

```
feval(f,[0.4 2 3],[4 5 6])
```

returns: [8.4  12  15]
instead of [8.4 7 9].

What is the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` condition doesn't work element-wise, as you seem to expect. Rather, the `if` branch is entered only if all the elements in the expression (`x>0.5` in your case) evaluate to `true`.

To achieve what you want, change your function to

```
function z = f(x,y)
    ind = x>.5;
    z(ind) = x(ind) + y(ind);
    z(~ind) = x(~ind) + 2*y(~ind);
end
```

Note that the [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) `ind` takes the place of your `if`.

For your particular function, the code could be simplified to

```
function z = f(x,y)
    z = x + y + (x<=.5).*y;
end
```

Comment: Ok, but I do NOT want to change the function. Here is a very simple example, but for applications f will be much more complicated. So no "if" with vectorization ? I have to use a loop ?

Comment: `if [0 1]` is always `false`. It is not "`false` for the first entry and `true` for the second". You can see it this way: `if` applies an implicit `and` to all entries. To work element-wise, use a logical index as in my answer. Or of course you could use a loop